# Create generator from list of generators

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I want to create Generator from multiple generators.
I have list of generators

```
val generators: List[Gen] = List(Gen[Int], Gen[Double], Gen[String], ...)
```

I don't know what is the size of the list, it could be any size

I want to create something like this:

```
val listGen: Gen[List[Any]] = createListGenerator(generators)
```

Comment: `val listGen = Gen.sequence(generators)`?

Comment: I found it like this: val listGen: Gen[util.ArrayList[Nothing]] = Gen.sequence(generators)

, I want it to by : Gen[List[Any]]

Comment: Getting `Gen[util.ArrayList[Nothing]]` is odd. Are you sure you're not seeing `Gen[java.util.ArrayList[Any]]`? Is the type of `generators` `List[Gen[Any]]` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `listGen` to give you an arbitrary number of elements in an arbitrary order that are drawn from one or more of the generators in `generators`, you can do the following:

```
// Scala's type inference gets a bit finicky when combining Anys with CanBuildFroms
val comboGen = Gen.sequence[List[Any], Any](generators).flatMap(Gen.oneOf[Any])
val listGen = Gen.listOf(comboGen)
```

Alternatively, if you want to have exactly the same number of elements get generated by `listGen` as there are elements in `generators` and in the same order, you can simply do

```
val listGen = Gen.sequence[List[Any], Any](generators)
```

Comment: I don't know what will be the size of the list, it can be any size.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now in your question. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

We start with a list of generators

```
val generators: List[Gen[Any]] = ???
```

Next we create a generator which generates elements by choosing one generator and yielding the item generated by that generator:

```
val genOne: Gen[Any] = for {
  gen <- Gen.oneOf(generators)
  item <- gen
} yield item
```

We can use this generator to create a list generator

```
val listGen: Gen[List[Any]] = Gen.listOf(genOne)
```

This list generator generates a list (possibly empty) which can contain items generated by the generators in the original `generators` List, however not all generators are always included, and the order is random.

For example if the `generators` List contained a `Gen[Int]`, `Gen[Double]` and a `Gen[String]`, then the lists generated by `listGen`. Will contain any amount of ints, doubles and strings in any order.

Comment: I need the result List[Any] to be the same order like generators